# Prevent wrapping in CSS Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, ellipsis

I have a re-sizable sidebar using Javascript. The problem is when the size of the sidebar is less than the content's wrapping occurs. (i think because of flex-box).

My grid is based on Rows and Columns kinda like Bootstrap.

```
.column {
    flex-basis: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    margin: 0 -1rem;
}
```

What I want to achieve is truncating the content (without shrinking) indicating that there is more.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g7y3bgfh/4/) with what i achieved so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it comes to Flexbox, you need to set `min-width: 0` or `overflow: hidden` to every level, down from the child of the element with the width constraint, to the one having ellipsis.

So in this case, from the `sidebar`'s child, and the reason is that a flex item's `min-width` defaults to `auto`, which mean it can't be smaller than its content.

To make it easy to follow how I mean, I created a `flex-ellipsis` class and added it to all elements down that chain.

*Note, I also removed the negative margin, `margin: 0 -1rem;`, from the `row` class, or else one can't see the ellipsis.*

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g7y3bgfh/6/)

Stack snippet

```js
const resizeHandle = document.getElementsByClassName("vertical-resize")[0];
const navbar = document.getElementById('sidebar');

function resizeNavbar(e) {
  let size = (e.pageX + 5);

  navbar.style.width = (e.pageX + 5) + "px";
}

function removeEvents() {
  document.removeEventListener('mousemove', resizeNavbar);
  document.removeEventListener('mouseup', resizeNavbar);
}

resizeHandle.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', resizeNavbar);
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', removeEvents);
});
```

```css
* {
  user-select: none;
  color: #dadada;
}

.flex-ellipsis {
  min-width: 0;                          /*  added  */
  /* or overflow: hidden; */
}

p,
h6 {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.rounded-circle {
  border-radius: 50% !important;
}

.no-margin {
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.column {
  flex-basis: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: #4a4a4a;
}

.column-1 {
  flex: 0 0 8.33333%;
  max-width: 8.33333%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap; /*Even though no-wrap it still wraps as shown in picture.*/
  /*margin: 0 -1rem;*/
}

.custom {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.vertical-resize {
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  cursor: col-resize;
  width: 5px;
  background: aquamarine;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div id="sidebar" style="width: 570px;">
    <div class="align-items-center row custom flex-ellipsis" id="sidebar">
      <div style="max-width: 2.5rem;" class="column-1">
        <img class="rounded-circle" style="max-width: 28px; min-width: 28px;" alt="Avatar" src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/138926-200.png">
      </div>
      <div class="column flex-ellipsis">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column">
            <p class="no-margin">Ahmed Tarek</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row flex-ellipsis">
          <div class="column flex-ellipsis">
            <h6 style="font-size: 11px;" class="no-margin">01 January, 0001</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="vertical-resize"></div>
  <div class="column">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's it!, Many thanks for such detailed answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

You need to use text-overflow property along with other properties inside a media query or per your needs.

e.g

```css
.list {
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 48px; /* just for test */
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  this is a ver long list this is a ver long list this is a ver long list.
</div>
```

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: +1 for the white-space nowrap this is pretty close actually to work except that i don't get the desired `...` from the text-overflow for some reason.

Comment: Are you unable to see it in the snippet? or in your page? And You can vote up for +1 :)

Comment: It works in the snippet yet in my code it doesn't. So far it just prevents the white space wrapping which is pretty close to what i want. Please see the updated question with more explanation.

Comment: Also are you using the overflow property?

Comment: yea... i am trying to put a fiddle together but it's kinda hard.

Comment: Update the question with a fiddle.

Comment: @AhmedTarek, you are doing it wrong. The code i share will work on the text elements not on layouts. If you add the css to the Full Name paragraph then it will work.

Comment: If you take a look at the fiddle now that i added the vertical bar you can see that it works but shows the eclipses on the other side of the bar which in my application is another column (resulting in the dots not showing)

Answer (score 0):

As you have not shared full code with us, it will be difficult for us to provide you working solution. But you can add this css to your code with you want to truncate.

```css
width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
```

This will help you with text truncate with "..."